# aws managed service handling large number of small files

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, file, types, io

It is expected to around 1,000,000 json files will be generated per day from the on-premise system (not going to the internet) and expected to be aggregated for analytics. Each text file is less than 4 kb.

My current thought is to use AWS DataSync to upload the files to s3. Using s3 to store the file, saying 3 years. I am not sure what service to use to do the analytics.

But AWS good practice is that Athena and Glue are good at handling the small number of large files, and we should try to avoid the large number of small files.

So is there any existing AWS service that is good at aggregating this kind of data?

Thanks!

Comment: You can dump JSON files as flat data in Redshift. Redshift is best for group by and aggregations.

Comment: Would it be fast?

Comment: Handling such a large number of small files is always going to be difficult (and expensive in terms of time and money). Would it be possible to aggregate the files together, or perhaps send the data to Amazon Kinesis Firehose instead of S3 and have it save aggregated data in fewer files? What is the lifecycle of these files -- do they need to be kept? Having multiple millions of objects in S3 makes it very difficult to manage. Please Edit your question and provide this extra information rather than answering in a comment.